# Get full name by log in name in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, profile, user-profile

Is there an easy way to retrieve fullname e.g "John Smith" from its login name "j.smith" in sharepoint? Ive been ages looking for that code.

I have this code:

```
   string strName = SPUtility.GetAccountName("j.smith");
```

Where strName should be my fullname and "j.smith" is my login name. I dont think its correct..any advice from sharepoint masters out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user whose full name needs to be fetched is already added to the site or it is Ok that the user be added to the site you can use :

```
  web.EnsureUser(LoginName).Name
```

Alternatively you can use User profile service and get the full name of the user from his user profile if  the user is not added to the site and you do not want to add that user to the site.

```
 SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
 UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context);
 UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(@"zsdev\ia"); 
Console.WriteLine(profile.DisplayName);
```

Comment: thanks! i still hae a problem tho, how can I search for "j.smith" only? if i am not given the "machine\\" ? i am only given the "j.smith" parameter. not "machine\\j.smith" hope u cn help

Comment: like the ones on ur pm.GetUserProfile(@"zsdev\ia"); .. I am only given "ia" as a parameter, not "zsdev\\ia"

Comment: simply mentioning the loginname ie "j.smith" without AD name will also work if Sharepoint is connected to single domain or even if connected to multiple domains but the loginName is unique for both the domains ie there is only one "j.smith" in all the connected domains.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a current SPWeb you can use web.EnsureUser(loginName).Name.

Comment: I did that but it had this error  <nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.

Comment: I think its updating my users.. EnsureUser method Checks whether the specified logon name belongs to a valid user of the website, and if the logon name does not already exist, adds it to the website. ..... (which is unnecessary) other ways just to get the fullname??